# Explanation of operator precedence in an if statement

Tags: c++, operator-precedence

Example code:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    if(int a = std::cin.get() && a == 'a')
    {
        std::cout << "True" << std::endl;
    }
}
```

**Question**:

When I compile this code, visual studio gives me a nice warning: `warning C4700: uninitialized local variable 'a' used`. So I understand that `a` is uninitialized. However, I wanted to fully understand how the expression is evaluated. Is it the case that the if statement above is equivalent to `if(int a && a == 'a') { a = std::cin.get(); }`? Could someone explain exactly what happens?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The and operator `&&` has higher precedence than the assignment operator `=`. So in other words, your statement is being executed like this:

```
if (int a = (std::cin.get() && a == 'a'))
```

You really want to use explicit parentheses:

```
int a;
if ((a = std::cin.get()) && a == 'a')
```

Even better, write clear code:

```
int a = std::cin.get();
if (a == 'a')
```

:-)

Comment: And, as long as you have to do it in two separate statements, you may as well do the initialization with the declaration and simplify the conditional: `int a = std::cin.get(); if (a == 'a')`.

Comment: @RobKennedy: Yes, I've always avoided issues like this by breaking the statements up, but I just wanted a good understanding.

Comment: @RobKennedy Very true; I was tempted to put that, but I wanted to get my answer out quickly. :-) Editing shortly.

Answer (score 0):

The expression gets evaluated just as if it was its own statement. Like this:

```
int a = std::cin.get() && a == 'a';
```

So it's equivalent to initialize a variable `a` with the result from `std::cin.get()` ***AND-ed*** with the comparison between an uninitialized variable and the literal char `'a'`.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the variable to initialize itself. First the memory is allocated then whatever was in that memory is compared to 'a' and the result used to initialize the variable.